# XML Files in Magento

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento2, symphony-cms

How to exactly know what to write and edit in xml files of magento.
I mean if we are making a module or a theme how to exactly edit the xml files.

e.g If we need a header we just write  tag in html. I mean is there a specification for every tag that is being used and why?

P.S : I have used XML for only showing data in table format.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for XML for the frontend module like a theme in Magento 2, you need to understand and follow the layout instructions to wireframe the page. Follow the below guidelines:

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/xml-instructions/
https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/layouts/